# Sign up not communicating with api properly with react-redux

Tags: reactjs, api, webpack, redux, user-input

I am trying to follow a thinkster tutorial that creates a medium clone.  There are a variety of languages and frameworks you can choose to do this.  I chose react's pathway.  Things are starting to break... First of all, I have all of these 'problems' linked to webpack warnings.  Can I get rid of these if they aren't important?

**Main Issue**
I think something is wrong with how my files are trying to communicate with the API it is using to simulate a backend.  I keep seeing that the app cannot connect to API_ROOT.  I think this is where my problem stems from.  The API also fils the homepage with content and has a 'loading' state when the articles are loading.  This state, in my testing, is never seen.  The articles used to just show up.  I also think something could be fishy with agent.js... Here are the errors I get.  I'll use a screenshot to show the ones that are very similar and put the one that I think is the issue below.  Also below is a link to my repository on github that is in the current, nonworking state.  Thanks a bunch folks!
[image]

```
home.js:15 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'articles' 
of null
    at exports.default (home.js:15)
    at combination (combineReducers.js:133)
    at dispatch (createStore.js:178)
    at eval (middleware.js:47)
    at eval (middleware.js:29)
    at Object.dispatch (applyMiddleware.js:45)
    at eval (middleware.js:21)
```

Here my github link: [my github repo](https://github.com/rockomatthews/react-projects.git)

Answer (score 1):

In `react-redux-realworld-example-app/src/agent.js` you seem to be using regular quotes `'`.
`superagent.get('${API_ROOT}${url}')`
Everything in regular quotes will be a string (e.g. the value will actually be '${API_ROOT}${url}'.

You can use ES6 string interpolation -  `${API_ROOT}${url}` which will correctly concatenate values for you.

Comment: ahhh.  I actually saw that ES6 string interpolation, thought it looked weird, and changed them to normal quotes.  thanks.  will try

Comment: so I made the change.  I am still getting this error:

        client.js:841 POST https://conduit.productionready.io/api/users 
        422 
    (Unprocessable Entity)


NEVERMIND.  It seems to be working!  Thanks